# Rugged Capacitive Single Touch Screen

Tags: touchscreen, capacitive

I am looking to make a capacitive single touch screen into a small table. Which I can use to put coffee cup etc on. It does not have to be waterproof but rugged enough to not scratch over time easily or break. There is a number of touch screens available but none seem to be rugged for this kind of use.

What can I use on top of the screen to make it durable without losing the touch capabilities of the screen? 
Or are there screens like that available for a reasonable cost?

Comment: Why does it have to be capacitive? The most rugged ones use IR emitters and receivers contained in a bezel around the edge of your surface, which can then be made of anything you want.

Comment: Something like a sheet of Gorilla glass comes to mind, smartphones work quite well I hear...